# How to bind default value in select in react which are dependent on each other values are coming from Api?

Tags: reactjs, select, react-hooks, formik

This is below code where i am using to fetch values.In country I am managing countries and on the base of country when formik detects there there is change in country and if country Id exists so use effect is called and bind states based on that country if same for states and cities are updated based on stateId not in case of edit e.g. if i am fetching data from API and i am receiving all ids from API the select  is not getting binded with default value except countryId as country is independent

````
    const [countries, setCountries] = useState<any>([]);
      const [states, setStates] = useState<any>([]);
      const [cities, setCities] = useState<any>([]);
      const [previousCountryId, setPreviousCountryId] = useState<number | null>(null);
      const [previousStateId, setPreviousStateId] = useState<number | null>(null);
      
      const countryIdRef = useRef<number>(formik.values.countryId);
      const stateIdRef = useRef<number>(formik.values.stateId);
      
      const bindCountries = () => {
        getAllCountries()
          .then((res: any) => {
            if (res.data.status) {
              let data = res.data.data;
              setCountries(data);
            } else {
              setCountries([]);
            }
          })
          .catch(() => {
            setCountries([]);
          });
      };
     ``` 
      const bindStates = (countryId: number) => {
        getStatesByCountry(countryId)
          .then((res: any) => {
            const array = res.data.data;
            setStates(array);
          })
          .catch((err: any) => {
            console.log(err);
          });
      };
      ```
    ```
      const bindCities = (stateId: number) => {
        getCitiesByState(stateId)
          .then((res: any) => {
            const array = res.data.data;
            setCities(array);
          })
          .catch((err: any) => {
            console.log(err);
          });
      };
      ```
    ```
      const handleCountryChange = (value: number) => {
        countryIdRef.current = value;
        setPreviousCountryId(formik.values.countryId);
        formik.setFieldValue('countryId', value);
      };
      ```
    ```
      const handleStateChange = (value: number) => {
        stateIdRef.current = value;
        setPreviousStateId(formik.values.stateId);
        formik.setFieldValue('stateId', value);
      };
      ```
    ```
      useEffect(() => {
        bindCountries();
      }, []);
      ```
    ```
    ```
      useEffect(() => {
        if (previousCountryId !== formik.values.countryId && formik.values.countryId !== 0 && formik.values.countryId != undefined) {
          setStates([]);
          setCities([]);
          bindStates(formik.values.countryId);
        }
      }, [formik.values.countryId, previousCountryId]);
    ```
      ```
      useEffect(() => {
        if (previousStateId !== formik.values.stateId && formik.values.stateId !== 0 && formik.values.stateId != undefined) {
          setCities([]);
          bindCities(formik.values.stateId);
        }
      }, [formik.values.stateId, previousStateId]);
      ```
    ```
      useEffect(() => {
        if (tourId == null || tourId == undefined) {
          formik.setFieldValue('cityId', 0);
        }
      }, [tourId]);
    ```
    ```
      useEffect(() => {
        setStates([])
        setCities([])
        if (tourId != null && tourId != undefined) {
          formik.setFieldValue('stateId', 0)
          formik.setFieldValue('cityId', 0)
        }
        if (formik.values.countryId !== 0 && formik.values.countryId!= undefined) {
          bindStates(formik.values.countryId)
        }
      }, [formik.values.countryId])
      useEffect(() => {
        setCities([])
        // if page is edit page then dont set cityId to 0
        if (tourId == null || tourId == undefined) {
          formik.setFieldValue('cityId', 0)
        }
        if (formik.values.stateId !== 0 && formik.values.stateId!= undefined) {
          bindCities(formik.values.stateId)
        }
      }, [formik.values.stateId])



  <FieldSelect
        className='col-lg-6'
        isRequired
        label='Country'
        name='countryId'
        formik={formik}
        onChange={handleCountryChange}
        defaultValue={formik.values.countryId}
      >
        <option value={0}>Select Country</option>
        {countries.map((item: any) => {
          return (
            <option key={item.id} value={item.id}>
              {item.name}
            </option>
          )
        })}
      </FieldSelect>
<FieldSelect className='col-lg-6'
       onChange={handleStateChange}
       defaultValue={formik.values.stateId}
        isRequired label='State' name='stateId' formik={formik}>
        <option value={0}>Select State</option>
        {states.map((item: any) => {
          return (
            <option key={item.id}
            selected={item.id === formik.values.stateId} // <-- set selected prop 
            value={item.id}>
              {item.name}
            </option>
          )
        })}
      </FieldSelect>
````

Comment: <FieldSelect
        className='col-lg-6'
        isRequired
        label='Country'
        name='countryId'
        formik={formik}
        onChange={handleCountryChange}
        defaultValue={formik.values.countryId}
      >
        <option value={0}>Select Country</option>
        {countries.map((item: any) => {
          return (
            <option key={item.id} value={item.id}>
              {item.name}
            </option>
          )
        })}
      </FieldSelect> this is  UI setup